# How to know if browser blocks plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I need to know if browser is blocking a plugin, specifically Unity web player. In that case I want to tell the user how to unlock the plugin.
I try with `navigator.plugins` but recognizes like active so it's useless.
Anyone know how could I get this?

Thanks

Edit: Also the function of the unity API `getUnity` returns me the object instead of `null` because the object is already initialized

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[Calling web page functions from Unity web player content](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)".
Call a javascript from unity that would set a variable on the page, with a page `timeout` script that would check the variable and show the message after a few seconds

Comment: I did it in that way. I put a 10 seconds timer, but still its unreliable because the user connection could be slow or the object be too heavy

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Unity Web Player | Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
    if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
      unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "Example.unity3d", 600, 450, null, null, unityLoaded);
    }

    function unityLoaded(result) {
        if (result.success) {
          var unity = result.ref;
          var version = unity.GetUnityVersion("3.x.x");
          alert("Unity Web Player loaded!\nId: " + result.id + "\nVersion: " + version);
        } else {
          alert("Please install Unity Web Player!");
        }
      }        
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This will be replaced by Unity content. -->
  <div id="unityPlayer">Unity content can't be played. Make sure you are using compatible browser with JavaScript enabled.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I use UnityObject2 and its a little bit different